# build aosp for z2460 x86

Tags: android, android-source, android-x86

I need help with building aosp (4.0.4, 4.1, 4.2) for Intel's Atom z2460 based tablets.

Any known port out there ?

Is it possible with aosp or android-x86 projects ?

Please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the x86 source code you can look at the following website

http://www.android-x86.org/getsourcecode

Comment: i need to actually build for several versions, and android-x86 build fails.